# Ubuntu 16.04 Snappy image in azure

Tags: 15.04, 16.04, snap

Wondering if there is any Azure Image with Snappy in Ubuntu core 16.04? From the instructions in the [doc](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-azure) I could see only 15.04 Images in Azure. Are Snappy Images are customized? Or Is it better to go ahead with existing 16.04 Image and install snappy over that?

I can't use 15.04 because when I install my snap in that image I getting [error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1536864) as which is already known developers.

Answer (score 2):

There are no official snappy Ubuntu Core 16 images just yet. They'll be released soon (though I'm not sure how they get into Azure); until then you'll need to use snappy from the 16.04 server or desktop install.